# How to make the method fill the list with values from different tables and fields in one list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to make a method that will populate the `lst_List` list with rows from various tables and fields.
Preliminary version of the code:

```
cntDB = new ContextDB();
 List<List<string>> lst_List = new List<List<string>>();
 public void Method_2(string nameTable, string nameField)
        {
            var phones = cntDB.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT " + nameField + " FROM " + nameTable); // +-
            lst_List.AddRange(phones.ToList());
        }
```

How to make the method fill the list with values from different tables and fields in one list?

Comment: You should explain what's the problem with above code snippet. 
As far I understood, you would like to pass field name and table name at run time and it should return non filtered matched whole column matched with the string passed in "nameField".

Comment: if you are using entity framework why do you want to use ExecuteSqlCommand for such a trivial operation which is select from the table. Why not using LINQ?

Comment: @Usman  Yes. You understood correctly.

Comment: @GoldenAge I use `ExecuteSqlCommand` because I don’t understand how to pass the `nameTable` and `nameField` parameters to the LINK query.
 I would be grateful if you offer your option.

Comment: @eusataf : of course, executing queries dynamically, either you need to use D-Linq or some other approach where you can pass strings and that can be translated. But my question is: what is the problem with above code snippet? Is it not returning what you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteSqlCommand` returns an `int` not the result set and is used primarily for non-SELECT commands (e.g. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). Use `SqlQuery` instead:

```
cntDB = new ContextDB();
 List<string> lst_List = new List<string>();
 public void Method_2(string nameTable, string nameField)
        {
            var lst_List = cntDB.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT " + nameField + " FROM " + nameTable).ToList();
        }
```

You don't get a `List<List<string>>` this way but I can't see how you will populate that type from a single flat query as per your SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, You would like to populate list with different entries depending on given name and table.

Given on method with which You're trying to do that, I would make a class:

```
    private class DbTable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> Fields;
    }
```

Now You could modify Your method to take List of DbTable objects.

```
    public void Method_2(List<DbTable> tables)
    {
        foreach (var table in tables)
        {
            foreach (var field in table.Fields)
            {
                var phones = cntDB.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT " + field + " FROM " + table.Name); // +-
                lst_List.AddRange(phones.ToList());
            }
        }
    }
```

You need to instantiate a list that You want to pass to the method

```
        var tablesList = new List<DbTable>();
        var dbTable = new DbTable();
        dbTable.Name = "MyTableName";
        dbTable.Fields = new List<string>
        {
            "FirstField",
            "SecondField"
        };
        tablesList.Add(dbTable);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be easier to use LINQ:

```
var list = new List<List<string>>();
var FieldName1Rows = cntDB.TableName1.Select(x => x.FieldName1.ToString()).ToList();
list.Add(FieldName1Rows);
var FieldName2Rows = cntDB.TableName2.Select(x => x.FieldName2.ToString()).ToList();
list.Add(FieldName2Rows);
```

Comment: @eusataf want to pass table name at run time and similarly the fields from that table. The above code is only for compile time when you know which data table you are working with.